# Arduino ADK does not receive data from Galaxy S II over USB

Tags: java, android, arduino, galaxy, adk

I'm working on a project which relies on communication between my Galaxy S II and my Mega ADK.

The Arduino shows that it is beginning communication properly, and the S II is sending the USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED intent when it's connected, but the Arduino is incapable of reading any bytes sent to it.

Arduino code: http://pastebin.com/UiKzx1Rk

Android code: http://pastebin.com/f6PageAZ

Is this problem on the arduino side, or the android side?

Answer (score 1):

The ADK does actually support the Galaxy S II (I am currently using it to develop an accessory)

I am not sure where you problem is. But I suggest you take a look at this tutorial detailing how to control one LED from Android:
http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/

In this example (on the Arduino side) they are using the `read()` method on the `AndroidAccessory` object instead of `readBytes` which you are using. Perhaps you may want to try using `read()` as well.

Sorry my answer isn't of much help.

Answer (score 0):

ADK does not support Galaxy S II. Do you believe that? :(. I got this information from internet after I had just bought a Mega ADK today. If you find a solution for this problem, please write down here.